# How to add Jenkins master to Spinnaker

Tags: jenkins, spinnaker

I'm newby in Spinnaker and trying to build CI/CD deployment with spinnaker + jenkins.
I want to create automated trigger from Jenkins. but i couldn't add jenkins configuration in to Spinnaker.

this is current hal configuration

```
%hal config
ci:
  jenkins:
    enabled: true
    masters: []
  travis:
    enabled: false
    masters: []
```

and this is configuration file /opt/spinnaker/config/spinnaker-local.yml

```
services:
  igor:
    enabled: true
  jenkins:
    enabled: true
    defaultMaster:
      name: myjenkins
      baseUrl: http://myip:8080
      username: {my user id}
      password: {my password}
```

as u can see, i added jenkins configuration into spinnaker-local.yml
but when i test with curl command, i cannot find jenkins master

```
$ curl localhost:8084/v2/builds
[]
```

I'm using spinnaker 1.5.4 and Jenkinx 2.8X version

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [Halyard](https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/install/halyard/) to enable the Jenkins CI, and configure the master, instead of modifying the configs directly.

```
hal config ci jenkins enable
echo <JENKINS_PASSWORD> | hal config ci jenkins master add my-jenkins --address http://<JENKINS_URL> --username <JENKINS_USER> --password
hal deploy apply
```

The last command(`hal deploy apply`) actually deploys Spinnaker with the new Jenkins config applied.

Modifying the configs directly may work, but using Halyard is the recommended way to deploy Spinnaker, and works quite well.

Comment: While this works fine, when you want to enable CSRF for this jenkins, as per the documentation, you would also add --csrf true to above command. The moment you add this flag, the command errors out with - More than one master supplied.